# What is wrong with this auto-generated t-sql query?

Tags: .net, t-sql, datatable

I'm having trouble executing a stored proc...

I've got C# code that tries to call the stored proc.  It looks somewhat like this:

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", connection);
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myGuid", myGuid));
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
    da.Fill(myDataTable);
}
```

When I execute it, I get an error that reads "Incorrect syntax near 'MyStoredProc'".

If I run SqlProfiler, I see that it's attempting to run my stored proc like this:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'MyStoredProc',
N'@myGuid uniqueidentifier',
@myGuid='FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

And sure enough, if I try to do the same thing, I get the same error.  So my questions are:

1. What's wrong with the generated query?
2. Why is C# generating an invalid query?  Did I do something wrong in my C# code?

**EDIT:** Agent_9191 nailed it...I was foolishly leaving out the statement to set the selectCommand type to StoredProcedure.  The new generated query is:

```
exec MyStoredProc @myGuid='FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

and this (of course) works fine.

Comment: Please show the actual stored procedure that the error is occurring on. My hunch is that there's a problem with the SQL, not the C# code.

Comment: @Josh: nope...that's not it...I can replace 'MyStoredProc' with any random string of characters (non-existing stored proc) and I'll still get the error...it's really a syntax error in the call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure to set your `selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`.